# httplistener.Start() returns Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have IIS7 running on Window 2008 R2 server.
I have an MVC asp.net web app which I spawn an http listener from that web app and I keep getting

```
2015-07-30 11:25:12,306 [ERROR] [Integration.Orchestra.EventSources.HttpPostStringServer] Failed to start Http Post Listener. System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): Access is denied
at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
```

I use localhost as host name and 999 as port.
I have search around the web and I tried to run the following command :

> netsh http add urlacl url="http://*:999/Context" user=everyone listen=yes

Any idea of what may cause this? I log in as administrator, I even tried to run the above command by setting user=MYDOMAIN\administrator

Comment: May I ask why you start an HttpListener from a web app? Anyway change `http://*:999/Context` to `http://+:999/Context`.

Comment: I was asked to tie the logics of the web app... so somone can send an http post that can mimic to certain type of button being pressed on the web ui.  Yup, I did try the +, i tried localhost, 127.0.0.1 as well.

Comment: That's what you build an API for, so your web app and the external party can send requests to the API. See the edit about the urlacl, you need `+` isntead of `*`. Also try `user=\Everyone` (note the backslash and the capitalization). Is your Windows English? See [WCF selfhosted service, installer class and netsh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521950/wcf-selfhosted-service-installer-class-and-netsh).

Comment: I totally with you on the api but I think the reason for built in http because this is a very small web app that literally has one page display.

Comment: Hi CodeCaster, if you put in your answer, I'll accept it.  It turns out what you said, the user account that runs the ApplicationPool.  I ended up changing it to the local system account and it works.  My next step would be to figure out the way to change that applicationpoolidentity's permission.